# Adding Whitespace to an SVG

Tags: css, svg, web-deployment, squarespace

Not too knowledgeable on vector graphics but throwing together a website for a hobby and am using an SVG as a background image. Found a great image here that I'd like to use but I'd like there to be more whitespace above the mountains: https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/#flat-mountains

Is there an easy way to do this? I've been out of the web dev game for a bit now and simple searching lead me to "background-position:" and that pushes the image down but I end up with the bottom of my image coming down into the top of my screen. Is there an easy way to just add some whitespace here so that the mountains start a little lower?

Don't have the site live yet to show you or I would.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the `wiewBox` of your SVG: use -300 (for example) instead of 0 for the `y`: background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 **-300** 1600 900'%3E%3Cpolygon

Comment: Changing the `viewBox` as suggested above would work depending on what you'd like to do. I'd download the SVG and edit it to look how you'd like in a graphics editor. https://gravit.io/ - is a free online graphics editor. 

If you wanted to do it with CSS I'd add the `background-color` the parent. add the SVG to the child with a fixed height using `vh` units.

`
.parent { background-color: rgb(255, 119, 0); )

.child { 
    background-image: `url('your-svg'); 
    height: 90vh;
}
`